# Compare the differences between two backbone models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have an app that updates backbone models between two clients over websockets.

I'd like to keep the sync procedure very generalized so I'm aiming to be able to deflate the model send JSON over the wire and inflate on the other client.

I have all this working perfectly except right now I inflate the model in place clobbering the old one. As far as I know this means everything changes state and everything renders itself again.

How should I go about comparing and applying only changed attributes of the model on the receiving end?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're taking a hash of attributes from the remote model, and calling

```
localModel.set remoteModelHash
```

In that case, for each of the attributes in that hash, a `change` event is triggered *only for those whose values are different* (more precisely, those who fail a [_.isEqual](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEqual) test). Which means that you shouldn't have views rendering unnecessarily, etc.

You can test this by checking

```
localModel.changedAttributes()
```

after the `set` call.

Comment: nifty tip Trevor. Glad to catch this in my feeds, although I'm not actively synchronizing state between nodes at the moment.